# Blocking Tor By Trying to Connect to an Entry Node

Tags: tor

So, I had an idea on how to block Tor (or similar tools) from being used on your network (or ISP, which is perhaps more relevant, considering Tor's mission). I'm assuming it wouldn't work (based on the assumption that the US Navy is smarter than me), but I'm not sure why not. So, here's how I'm thinking it would work:

1. Tor is secured by SSL (or a similar scheme), but the AP can still see who you're sending information to (the entry node). So they look to see who you're "contacting."
2. Next, the AP tries to contact that IP. Unless the entry node doubles as a webserver (thinking that's not too likely), the node will block the connection.
3. If it does, block the traffic.

This would obviously halve (or come close to halving) broadband available to people using the network, but would it work? Or have the Tor people found some way around it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the AP can still see who you're sending information to"?  The entry node does not see the end destination IP.

Comment: @raz Yes, but the AP can see the entry node's IP, right?

Comment: Each node only negotiates with the next node.  The Tor protocol ensures that only the client knows the keys for each node.  The nodes themselves don't know anything past the next node they're communicating with.

Comment: Yes, but the AP only needs to see the entry node's IP. Then it can try to connect to that IP, and, unless the computer is a server as well as a Tor node, the connection will be refused, right? So the AP knows the connection is via Tor.

Comment: Yeah that's your problem.  Any [webserver can enable Tor](http://www.bsdnow.tv/tutorials/tor), and be a relay on the network.  That's just a BSD example, but Tor relies on volunteers to be relays.  I don't think you can make the assumption that you won't be able to reach an IP just because it's on the Tor network.

Comment: @raz You're right, the idea couldn't possibly work with a 100% blocking rate. If you'd like to make that an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: Do you think on a wifi Access Point on the "AP"? This means, you are thinking mainly on a wireless environment? Which you didn't mention with a single word in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Tor is connection between normal end peers. Most of them *give* some revdns data, although it is not very informal and autogenerated (for example, 43.72.dyn.myprovider.com). Sometimes there is no revdns set up. But: it is totally independent if the end users are using tor, or not. It depends from the revdns settings of their network provider. Tor has nothing with them to do.

Although there are tor filters existing, they use a different method. They collect a list of the currently existing tor output gateways (there is not too many, and it can be easily asked), and check if the connection is coming from one of them.

Comment: OK, that makes sense for reverse DNS. But what about just trying to open a connection? Your typical computer will refuse it, but your typical server won't.

Comment: @KnightOfNi What are you talking about? This whole revdns and tor things are independent. Totally independent. Tor doesn't use revdns.

Comment: I never said it did... My question is clearly not well-phrased. I'll edit it to see if I can make it clearer.

Comment: OK, I hope the question makes more sense now. I took out the revDNS bit because this answer helped me to figure out that it clearly wouldn't work, so +1. Thanks!